# How to get sent/received bytes count by network adapter in C++/WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to get sent/received bytes count by network adapter in C++/WinAPI?

My programming platform is Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the function [`GetTcpStatistics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366020.aspx) and related ones (`GetUdpStatistics` etc.).

On second thought: [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373088.aspx) would probably provide another method that is more tailored to your needs. This can also be queried via WMI ([`Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394293.aspx)).

Comment: Hello, I used GetIfTable dwInOctets to get received total bytes. Your suggestions are just working fine as well but the problem is; Wi-Fi status shows always lesser values than you get from API. Why is that?

Comment: @BurakDay sorry, never noticed your comment. My guess would be the protocol overhead. I imagine that the counted bytes are payload bytes for the respective protocol(s).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get info just like from "netstat -e" I suggest using [GetIfTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, it returns table with [MIB_IFROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures which hold the info about out/in bytes in **dwOutOctets** and **dwInOctets**.

Comment: Hello, I used GetIfTable dwInOctets to get received total bytes. Wi-Fi status shows always lesser values than you get from API. Why is that?